# Python Pandas Keep counting until the next value appears

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this and would like to generate the 'count of revisit' using Python pandas.

[image]

Alternatively, having a summary table like below is also acceptable.

[image]

But wonder if there is any function in pandas that can allow me to do so.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['count of revisit'] = (df['Type of visit'].eq('revisit')
                          .groupby('customer A').transform('sum')
                         )
```

For the alternative:

```
out = (df['Type of visit'].eq('revisit')
       .groupby('customer A')
       .sum().reset_index(name='count of revisit')
      )
```

Note that if the number of revisits is just the number of rows minus 1, you can use:

```
df['count of revisit'] = (df.groupby('customer A')
                          ['customer A'].transform('size').sub(1)
                         )
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the transform functions?

Comment: `series.eq(xxx)` is equal to `series == xxx`, `groupby.transform('sum')` is equivalent to `groupby.sum` but instead of aggregating a single sum per group, it broadcasts the result to all original rows, like you want.

Comment: So we generate a boolean series with `True` on `'revisit'` and we count them per group with `sum`